# How can I stop my google map reloading every time I try to do something else off the map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have React Page. I splitted the page in 2. In the first half I have a form with some fields, and In the second half I have a Google Map Component. I added a Polyline. The path of the polyline gets updated every time the user left clicks (add point) or right clicks (remove point), or if it's dragged. Everything works well until I leave the map and focus on inputs or press some buttons in the other half. Then if I try to add new points or remove them ( this is not working because it has no points to remove) it starts a new polyline.

My methods are very simple, I took them from the docs and they do the job.

```
const addLatLng = (event) => {
    const path = poly.getPath();
    path.push(event.latLng);

  }
  const removeVertex = (vertex) => {
    let path = poly.getPath();
    path.removeAt(vertex)
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'rightclick', function (event) {
    if (event.vertex === undefined) {
      return;
    } else {
      removeVertex(event.vertex)
    }
  })
```

```
 <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
              <GoogleMap
                center={center}
                zoom={3}
                onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
                mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                onClick={(event) => { !showInputForLink && addLatLng(event) }}
              >
                
              </GoogleMap>

            </div>
```

First methods do the action and this is how I declared the map.

```
const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: ct.MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries: ['drawing, places']
  })
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */(null))  
const poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#160BB9',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    editable: true,
  });

  poly.setMap(map)
```

And this is how I declared the poly.

I tried to look up in Docs to see if I missed something, but I couldn't find anything that will not lose the focus on the map when I do something else or to start another polyline.

I am not using different components, everything is in on file.

Should I declare a Poly component inside the map? and not use the traditional JavaScript method?

How can I create this without resetting the map when I do actions in the first half?

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a codesandbox or fiddle that reproduces this issue? The community would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: It has no issues, the only thing is I want to know how to access all the objects within the map so I can clear the map.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. A codesandbox or a snippet would still be much appreciated.